# Variable not in scope: (/) :: a0 -> b0 -> c

Tags: haskell

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Ejercicio 2.20. Redefinir la función flip que intercambia el orden de sus argumentos.
>
> Por ejemplo,
>
> > `flip (-) 5 2  -- -3`
> >
> > `flip (/) 5 2  -- 0.4`

Solución:

```hs
import Prelude ()

flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y = f y x
```

Se supone que ya debería funcionara pero al momento de colocar los valores me manda

```
Variable not in scope: (/) :: a0 -> b0 -> c
```

¿Álguien me podría decir el porqué? Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces un `Prelude ()` estás impidiendo que tu código tenga acceso a todas las definiciones que hace prelude., incluyendo la definición de las funciones `(-)` y `(/)`, y muchas otras cosas.

Normalmente, el prelude se importa implícitamente para contar con una base de elementos con los que poder trabajar. Si haces un `Prelude ()` es porque quieres controlar qué elementos son visibles por tu código, pero vas a tener que ir poniéndolos a medida que el compilador te diga que no los encuentra.

Un modo de apañar tu código sería:

```hs
import Prelude ((/), (-), IO, putStr, ($))

flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y = f y x

main :: IO ()
main = putStr $ flip (/) 5 2
```

Pero vas a tener que ir ampliando la lista de elementos importados a medida que te vaya surgiendo la necesidad.

Mi recomendación es que dejes visible todo el módulo (quita ese import). Los elementos del prelude son básicos para poder trabajar cómodamente en haskell.

PD: algunos IDEs te pueden controlar qué elementos importar de cada módulo para tener un control total de la visibilidad entre módulos. En Visual Code te hubiera advertido que `(/)` no estaba visible y te hubiera dado la opción de hacerlo visible desde Prelude.